# mq_open err no 13 Permission denied

Tags: c, linux, posix, message-queue

I am running in to Permission issues while trying to create posix mq with mq_open() call. I did incorporate the change as mentioned here [mq_open Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780277/mq-open-eacces-permission-denied) I looked on other relevant post like this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.programmer/hnTZf6aPpbE but that also points to same thing.

Also while trying to compile I was running into error where mq calls were not identified and online it showed to compile by adding -lrt in gcc, post which was able to compile, mentioning it as I am not completely aware about rationale of it and didnt understand it by reading the post :)

**gcc server_mq.c -lrt -o server**

**error number is 13**

Oh dear, something went wrong with mqd ! **Permission denied**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "client_server.h"

#define PATH "/tmp/servermq"

int main(void)
{
    mqd_t mqd;
    mode_t omask;
    omask = umask(0);
    int flags = O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL;
    struct mq_attr attr, *attrp;

    attr.mq_maxmsg = 5;
    attr.mq_msgsize = 1024;

    attrp = &attr;

    mqd = mq_open(PATH, flags, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP, attrp);


    if (mqd == (mqd_t)-1)
    {
        printf("error number is %d \n ",errno);
        printf(" Oh dear, something went wrong with mqd ! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    umask(omask);
    mq_close(mqd);
    mq_unlink(PATH);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `/tmp/servermq` as your name...

Quoting **man mq_overvie**:

> ```
>    Message queues are created and opened using mq_open(3);  this  function
>    returns  a  message queue descriptor (mqd_t), which is used to refer to
>    the open message queue in later calls.  Each message queue  is  identi-
>    fied by a name of the form /somename; that is, a null-terminated string
>    of up to NAME_MAX (i.e.,  255)  characters  consisting  of  an  initial
>    slash,  followed  by one or more characters, none of which are slashes.
> ```

Also you will soon find this section relevant:

> **Mounting the message queue file system**
>              On  Linux, message queues are created in a virtual file system.  (Other
>              implementations may also provide such a feature, but  the  details  are
>              likely  to differ.)  This file system can be mounted (by the superuser)
>              using the following commands:
>
> ```
>            # mkdir /dev/mqueue
>            # mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
>
>        The sticky bit is automatically enabled on the mount directory.
> ```

Comment: thank u thank u ...spent 3 hrs debugging and looking online rather than reading man :( ...really appreciate the help !!!